# Cant get Microsoft Office for Mac 2011 to activate

Tags: microsoft-office, serial-number, software-activation

Ive got a Mac Mini that has had 2 new hard drives in its c. 4 year life, due to upgrading require storage form 500GB to 1TB to 2TB.

Each time i put a new HD i clone the contents from the old HD first, but some software requires that the serial number is re entered, before i use the software, ive done this in the past and it works fine.

This time though ive gone to input the serial number for Microsoft "Office for Mac 2011" and i get an error saying the activation server can not be reached (I have tried this on multiple occasions over the past couple of weeks, so do not think its a once in a blue moon "server is down" type error).

he license wizard suggest a I phone a toll free number and go through a phone activation process which requires me to input 9 blocks of 6 numbers into the phone and then receive 9 blocks of 6 numbers back to be re entered into the license wizard. Ive done this on other machines in the past and it worked fine, but this time after entering the 9 blocks of 6 numbers over the phone it said there was an error, so i tried again, but again got an error.

I called up the number again and this time it said there is a web site they can send me over text to my phone, to enter the 9 blocks of 6 numbers,  they sent me the link to the website over text, i entered the 9 blocks of 6 numbers, but again it failed.

I phoned Microsoft support who said that because this product "Office for Mac 2011" has been superseded by another product ("Office for Mac 2016") they no longer can offer support (frankly Im not asking for support i just want to activate a product that i rightfully own and their activation server is preventing me from doing so. But thats another storey)

Any ideas how i can get my software activated ?

Im running OSX 10.11.x.

[image: screenshot of office for mac activation failure requesting me to phone toll free number]

Comment: I assume you have tried to uninstall and reinstall the product?  Only after doing that did you try to activate the product?  Your assumption is correct, you should absolutely be able to activate the product, but you might also have reached your activation limit.  The human after an automated phone activation fails is supposed to be able to help you if that’s the case.  I would simply try my suggestion and try the online activation and if that fails try the phone activation again

Comment: @Ramhound ill try uninstalling the software, and then re install, currently i have it installed as part of the cloned files when the HDD was cloned, but maybe re installing it will re trigger it. I did think i might have hit the install limit, so i tried with another new serial number i had (never previously installed) and had exactly the same issue.

Comment: @Ramhound, i just uninstalled the software and re installed it, then inputted a serial number that hasn't been recycled previously, it still made me go through the telephone activation, but this time it worked !